# How to direct mypy to ignore type checking for multi-line imports

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Currently I have a multi-line import statement like this:

```
from my_module import (
    My_custom_class_1, My_custom_class_2, My_custom_class_3, 
    My_custom_class_4, My_custom_class_5, My_custom_class_6, 
)
```

In this case, I *do not* want to use `from my_module import *`. I also would like to ignore this file for type checking.

For single line imports, one can simply do `from my_module import * # type: ignore`, however this does not work for the multi-line case. I have tried adding after the last line, last parenthesis, after each line, etc.

Lastly, I don't want to add `# type: ignore` to the top of `my_module`.

So, is there a way to tell mypy to ignore multi-line imports like this? Or am I stuck with a 135 character line?

Comment: as a half-way solution you can split the import into a number of lines, maybe 2 or 3, and type ignore each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when mypy encounters line with implicit continuation because of parenthesis, it attaches all errors of that statement to that line. So ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=60341efe48be64f9a2eb3a640118b204))

```
from nothing import (  # type: ignore
    foo,
    bar, baz
)
```

passes type checking.

Same holds for multi-line def, for example:

```py
class Base:
    def foo(self, x: int) -> None: pass

class Child(Base):
    def foo(  # type: ignore[override]
        self,
        this_is_a_very_long_and_incompatible_argument: str,
    ) -> None: ...
```